# How costly it is to create a new IModel instance in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ .Net core client and I have many consumers consuming the same message.

The consumers should not wait for each other to finish so I am lunching each in a new thread.

I was registering IModel as a singleton in IOC

```
 services.AddSingleton(mb =>
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = HostName,
                UserName = Username,
                Password = Password,
                VirtualHost = VirtualHost
            };
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            return connection.CreateModel();
        });
```

but if I start my app and the queue already contains messages, I get the following exception:

> "Pipelining of requests forbidden"

I searched the issue and it seems like I can't pass the same IModel instance to multiple threads.

To override the issue I have two solutions, either register IModel as transient or use `lock` whenever I use IModel instance.

my question is: how costly it is to have a new instance of IModel whenever IModel is needed, hence a new connection to RabbitMQ will be initiated each time IModel is requested?

Is it worthy to use lock whenever an IModel instance is used?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how costly it is to have a new instance of IModel whenever IModel is
> needed

I am pretty confident that the performance is fine for your application. Benchmarks can be run if you need to prove something.

> ...hence a new connection to RabbitMQ will be initiated each time
> IModel is requested?

Why do you think that is the case? Have you run Wireshark on port `5672` to see what actually happens when `CreateModel` is called?

Spoiler alert: `CreateConnection` is what creates a connection, and `CreateModel` opens a channel on that connection. You are correct that you can't share `IModel` instances among threads, so create one per-thread. It will be fast enough!